# like operator gives zero results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I created a actionresult in `ASP MVC` which should show records matching with my `Linq` query. It was working correctly until I added:

```
records.State == '0' &&
```

This query (in t-sql) returns the correct results in  SQL management studio, but not with Linq:

```
   public ActionResult Index(string q)
    { 
               viewModel.Records = from records in db.records
                                   where records.State == '0' &&
                                   records.Title.Contains(q)
                                   || records.Title.Contains(q)
                                   ||records.Project.Contains(q)
                                   || records.Owner.Contains(q)
                                   || records.Number.Contains(q)
                                   select events;
    }
```

Comment: what is the Type of `State`  ?

Comment: @Shyju the type is tinyint

Comment: @CitizenDB Then why are you comparing it to a `char`?  Try `records.State == 0`.  By comparing to '0' you actually compare it to the numeric value 48

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful on how you put your logic. If what you want is

```
records.State == '0' && [whatever previous logic you have]
```

You should put all your previous logic in parentheses:

```
viewModel.Records = from records in db.records
                   where records.State == '0' &&
                   (records.Title.Contains(q)
                   || records.Project.Contains(q)
                   || records.Owner.Contains(q)
                   || records.Number.Contains(q))
                   select events;
```

Also, note that you have duplicate conditions `records.Title.Contains(q)`, I remove it in my solution.

In addition, if your `records.State` is of numeric type (like `int`, not `char/string`), then you should not use apostrophe, but should use the number directly:

```
viewModel.Records = from records in db.records
                   where records.State == 0 &&
                   (records.Title.Contains(q)
                   || records.Project.Contains(q)
                   || records.Owner.Contains(q)
                   || records.Number.Contains(q))
                   select events;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try below

```
public ActionResult Index(string q)
{ 
           viewModel.Records = from records in db.records
                               where records.State == 0 &&
                              ( records.Title.Contains(q)
                               || records.Title.Contains(q)
                               ||records.Project.Contains(q)
                               || records.Owner.Contains(q)
                               || records.Number.Contains(q))
                               select events;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work **if** the type of `State` property is of `char` type because `'0'` is a `char`

If `State` is of type `int`/`tinyint`(byte), you should do this

```
where records.State == 0 
&& records.Title.Contains(q)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.90).aspx) calls look correct (although you have `Title.Contains()` twice) but you mention that your `State` property is a `tinyint`, so you will want to compare it as such (instead of a string as you previously were):

```
public ActionResult Index(string q)
{ 
           viewModel.Records = from records in db.records
                               where records.State == 0 && (records.Title.Contains(q)
                               ||records.Project.Contains(q)
                               || records.Owner.Contains(q)
                               || records.Number.Contains(q))
                               select events;
}
```